# Problems compiling C++ code with boost library

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

I am trying to compile the  ([thomas pevny's source code to calculate the subtractive pixels adjacency matrix](http://dde.binghamton.edu/download/spam/)). This code asks to previously install the libboost and libpng library, which i done successfully.

but when I do the 'make' command, the following errors appears on the terminal.

```
spam.cpp:169:26: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::directory_entry’ has no member named ‘leaf’
spam.cpp:179:20: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string
```

Is there a way to fix this problem? Should I install another libboost version?

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`leaf()` is deprecated.

See this list of functions that are deprecated and their new names:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm

Edit for commment:

It should be something like this:

```
  boost::filesystem::path p("foo.txt");
  std::cout << p.filename() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I corrected the second error by replacing native_file_string with file_string(), but when I replace leaf() with path().filename(), there is another error. The piece of code is:    string fileName=file->path().filename(); //it was file->leaf() before.

Comment: The error is somethink like this: spam.cpp:168:42: error: conversion of ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to non scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ required

Comment: Thank you again salgar. But I want the code to run independently of the file name (i don want to inform the file name directly on the code). Is there a good way to change this piece of code? thank you again.

Comment: The piece of code is string fileName=file->path().filename(). Should I convert file->path().filename() to string?

Answer (score 2):

`leaf()` is deprecated. See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#directory_iterator-members
You can try to play without `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I corrected the second error by replacing native_file_string with file_string(), but when I replace leaf() with path().filename(), there is another error. The piece of code is: string fileName=file->path().filename(); //it was file->leaf() before. the variable file is a directory iterator. The error is The error is somethink like this: spam.cpp:168:42: error: conversion of ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to non scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ required

Comment: `path.filename()` is not of type `String` it is of type `path`. If you want to get the `String` from it you can try `native()` (`path.filename().native()`).

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Now I have the following error: spam.cpp:168:30: error:‘((boost::iterator_facade<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_entry, boost::single_pass_traversal_tag>*)(& file))->boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::operator-><boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_entry, boost::single_pass_traversal_tag, boost::filesystem3::directory_entry&, long int>()->boost::filesystem3::directory_entry::path’ does not have class type. I will keep on trying to fix it, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with @Salgar and @Jean-Baptiste Yunès suggestions and also by adding -lboost_system after -lboost_filesystem in makefile. Thank you everybody.